# How Does Scanf Find Keyboard Input?

Tags: io, keyboard, scanf

I was skimming through an implementation of scanf [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/libkern/stdio/scanf.c), and I couldn't find the exact method by which the program is picking up input from the keyboard. I know there's always another layer deeper to go, but could someone explain perhaps a step below C code, i.e. scanf, how keyboard input gets made available to my program?

Comment: The file name may be `scanf.c`, but if you look at the code, there is no `scanf()` function in it. That is the code for `sscanf()`.

Comment: Ah!! Darn it. Then I guess I better question would be where I could find an implementation, and even better, if someone could explain it...

Comment: A little work with a search engine turns up [this implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262.2.12/stdio/scanf.c) which hands off to `__svfscanf` which is implemneted [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-391.4.1/stdio/FreeBSD/vfscanf.c).

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact the file is called `scanf.c`, it contains only the `sscanf` and `vsscanf` functions (plus another internal function that's unimportant to the C library API).

Hence it's only used for scanning *strings* rather than reading from files.

In terms of how an *actual* `scanf` would work, it would usually just use the lower level functions in the C library, such as `getchar()` and `ungetc()`.

In terms of how *those* functions work, that's up to the implementation. It may call an lower level function yet again, it may have a memory mapped keyboard so it can just read memory to get a keystroke, it may receive interrupts and store keys in an ISR for later extraction.

The possibilities are very wide ranging.

---

For some *concrete* examples, I've developed a micro-processor emulator for the educational market that uses I/O ports for the keyboard (and other devices). So the lowest level code there is along the following lines:

```
:keyin  equ  07d2         ; memory mapped keyboard port
        push rf           ; preserve register
        setw rf :keyin    ; use register f for input
:loop   inb  r0 rf        ; get keyboard value to register 0
        jz   :loop        ; 0 means none available, so try again
        pop  rf           ; restore register f, register 0 now holds key
```

In contrast, (the much more successful) Linux can use one of the systems calls for reading a character from the input file descriptor:

```
buffer: db   ?
getch:  mov  eax, 3        ; sys_read
        mov  ebx, 0        ; descriptor 0 (input)
        mov  ecx, buffer   ; address to store data
        mov  edx, 1        ; get one character
        int  80h           ; make system call (old style).
```

Comment: @Anthony, just make sure you don't amend your question so that it's a totally different one. If you have a _different_ question, _ask_ it as a different question.

Comment: Hmm. I think my title is what I was asking, but the content got thrown aside by the bad link. Should I just make a new question?

Comment: I feel like that's a bit of a cop out, naturally I'm now wondering how getchar() works! Does the OS just have some defined way of reading the signals from my keyboard, that C just piggybacks off of?